# Framework for Media parsing from email html in java

Tags: java, email, parsing

I'm looking for open source lib. to parse email media and text.

Two main cases - First need to extract videos and audios from url, If available as well as attachments.
Second - Need to extract only main text from email body, not signature or headers i.e. Dear XYZ, Hello Mr..

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Commons email https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/ seems to be what you need. Some prefer Mime4J when parsing an email http://james.apache.org/mime4j/index.html. If you have to deal with HTML bodies you could use Jsoup http://jsoup.org/ to parse it and extract the media links.